# CDATA SFTP Connecter no file transfer

Tags: sql, ssis, sftp, ssdt-2017

at work we are trying to migrate some ssis packages from using ftp to sftp for file transfer. We bought the cdata connectors for ssis but all of them seem to be centered about data transfer or connecting to a file on the sftp server as the data source but don't say anything about file transfer over sftp.

Does anybody have any experience with these ? any information would help. please see below screen shots of the connectors

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've been in trouble with the same issue, and for me it was very strange to don't have the capability to transfer file using the Secure FILE TRANSFER Protocol.
I investigated the documentation of CData and I identified that it is possible to transfer files (upload or download) using Stored Procedures.

Here you can find the guide provided by CData to use these Stored Procedures:
http://cdn.cdata.com/help/SFF/rssis/pg_allsps.htm

Here you can find the guide to call Stored Procedures:
http://cdn.cdata.com/help/SFF/rssis/pg_ssisstoredprocedures.htm

For me, it worked fine to reach the expected result.